# Accessing value from bean:write in value attribute of logic:equal Struts

Tags: jsp, struts, logic, javabeans

I'm developing an application using Struts 1.3.10

I need to iterate 2 lists in order to print the result in jsp. The first list iteration needs to be used to select elements from list 2. For that reason I'm trying to do like this:

```
 <logic:iterate name="bodyForm" property="domainList" id="domList">
     <div><h1><bean:write name="domList" property="domain"/><h1>
          <ul> <logic:iterate name="bodyForm" property="locationsList" id="locList" >
                   <logic:equal name="locList" property="domain" value="<bean:write name="domList" property="domain"/>" >
                       <li><div>....</div></li>
                   <logic:equal>
               </logic:iterate>
           </ul>
     </div>
</logic:iterate>
```

But, when I call "bean:write" inside value of "logic:equal" I get an error. 
Do you know how to solve it?

As you sugest me I have used JSTL tags to get the solution, but in the source code of the web page I have this result:

```
    <h1>domList.domain</h1>
        <ul>
          <li class="grey">
             <div>locList.countries.name </div>
             <div>locList.name</div>
             <div>locList.hostname</div>
             <div>locList.ip</div>
          </li>
          <li class="">
             <div>locList.countries.name </div>
             <div>locList.name</div>
             <div>locList.hostname</div>
             <div>locList.ip</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

I seems that is not reading the bean information... Any idea?

Comment: You still haven't shown the code of your JSP.

Comment: I found the solution I miss to put value="${domList.domain}" in the notation of the jsp file.

Comment: My problem now is to iterate 2 times in the same bean. I mean, try to put hte same foreach iteration with the same "items" value to get two columns with different information. Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like an inefficient way of doing things, but of course it's possible. A forEach loop isjust like a for loop in Java. Nest any number you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn the JSTL and the JSP EL, and use it instead of these obsolete struts tags:

```
<c:forEach var="domList" items="${bodyForm.domainList}">
    <div>
        <h1><c:out value="${domList.domain}"/><h1>
        <ul> 
            <c:forEach var="locList" items="${bodyForm.locationsList}">
                <c:if test="${locList.domain == domList.domain}">
                    <li><div>....</div></li>
                </c:if>
           </c:forEach>
       </ul>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

AFAIR, the JSTL exists for something like 10 years. And since then, [the Struts documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/dev_logic.html) says:

> Note: - Many of the features in this taglib are also available in the JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL). The Apache Struts group encourages the use of the standard tags over the Struts specific tags when possible.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have used these tags but is not printing anything...

Comment: Then debug. What does the generated HTML look like? Have you added the JSTL core taglib declaration? Have you included the JSTL jar files in your webapp? Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: I have added de JSTL jar files and added tadlib, but the result in the screen is always the var name (as domList.domain, or locList.name) what I could be missing?

Comment: Don't look at the page displayed in the browser. Look at the generated HTML source code (using "View page source" in the browser). Tell us what it looks like, and show us the cource code of your JSP, by editing your question.