# Using another bean's property in the value attribute of a logic:equal tag

Tags: struts-1

I'd like to compare the properties of two separate beans using the logic tag in Struts1 :

```
<logic:equal name="beanOne" property="beanOneProperty" 
    value="<bean:write name="beanTwo" property="beanTwoProperty" />">

  //code to execute

</logic:equal>
```

But the above code results in the following error message:

> Unable to locate tag attribute info for tag attribute beanTwo.

How would I assign the value attribute to be what is stored in the second bean?

Is there a solution more succinct than this?

```
<bean:define id="beanTwoProperty" scope="request">
    <bean:write name="beanTwo" property="propOne"/>  
</bean:define>

<logic:equal name="beanOne" property="beanOneProperty" value="<%=beanTwoProperty">
```

---

My question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648311/accessing-value-from-beanwrite-in-value-attribute-of-logicequal-struts), though I'm interested in seeing if a pure-Struts-1 solution is available.

Comment: You could use the EL versions of the Struts 1 tags, but... when you don't need to use Struts tags, don't. The EL tags just duplicate functionality your container provides out of the box--they were written before EL was ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<bean:define ... />` as you've suggested

Or you could use EL:

```
<logic:equals name="beanOne" property="beanOneProperty" value="${beanTwo.beanTwoProperty}">
```

Or you could skip the `<bean:define ... />` (assuming a getter):

```
<logic:equals name="beanOne" property="beanOneProperty" value="<%= beanTwo.getBeanTwoProperty() %>">
```